# How to turn into conditional statements the equations of physics? Looking for basic examples ( at the high school physics, college physics level).

Tags: logic, mathematical-physics

My question is related to philosophy, but I do not ask for a philosophical answer. I would be interested in a  **technical answer from a logician's / mathematician's point of view**

In basic philosophy of science texts,  the name  of Karl Popper is often associated the claim that the basic form of a law of physics is

For all x ( if P(x) , then Q(x)).

Remark.- According to Popper, the fact that laws of physics are conditional statements is what makes them interesting, what gives them a cognitive value. That's what makes them risky statements, statements that can be tested.

What I am looking for is some examples of mathematical physics laws  that could actually be shown to have this conditional form. The problem ( for me) is that laws of physics are equations, I do not really know **how to turn an equation into a conditional statement.**

In basic texts, the examples given are oversimplistic, like :

For all x ( x is a raven --> x is black).

Remark.- I have no knowledge of advanced physics.

Comment: Are you after something like: Newton's third law states that for every action there is an equal and opposite reaction (as an equation, $F_B = -F_A$ where $F_B$ is the force $B$ exerts on $A$ and $F_A$ is the force $A$ exerts on $B$).  This can be written as "For all forces, *if* a force acts on an object *then* there is an equal force opposing it"?

Comment: @Postmortes. Yes, you're right, this is a good example. I would also like some less fundamental laws, laws that can not be suspected to be disguised definitions. ( Because I think definitions can not really be tested, they are conventional. According to Popper , a scientific law is interesting in asmuch as it can be submitted to a test).

Comment: @EleonoreSaintJames Newton's third law is hardly a definition, although the way we _understand_ it might be. It can be tested. We test it so much, constantly, without observing any failure, that it _seems_ axiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $O$ is an object that started at rest and has since been falling without resistance in a uniform gravitational field, if $g$ is the gravitational acceleration in that field, if $t$ is the time that $O$ has been falling, and if $s$ is the distance that $O$ has fallen, then $s = \frac12 gt^2.$

What might be missing from an oversimplified view of Popper's claim is that
$x$ might have many components (in the case above, we can identify at least
$O,$ $g,$ $t,$ and $s$) and that $P(x)$ might have a large number of clauses.

To put it another way, if you write down any equation of physics, an equation $Q(x)$ tells us nothing about the physical world until someone has said what each of the symbols in the equation *means.* The assignment of meaning to the symbols is $P(x),$ and it's what makes $Q(x)$ part of a physical law rather than just a random, meaningless equation.

Answer (score 1):

For all objects $O_v$ moving with velocity $v>0$: if there is no force applied to $O_v$, then $O_v$ maintains its velocity $v$.

For all objects $O_{m,v}$ in the universe with rest mass $m \geq 0$ and velocity $v>0$: if the rest mass $m$ of $O_{m,v}$ is strictly positive, then the velocity $v$ of $O_{m,v}$ is smaller than the speed of light.

For all thermodynamic systems $T_{E}$ with internal energy $E$: if $T_{E}$ is a closed system, then $E$ must stay constant for all time.

Comment: @ Joker123. Thanks a lot!  If ever you had the idea of less fundamental laws ( maybe from  optics , acoustics, etc) I would be much interested. As I said to Postmortes in a previous commentary, I fear that such fundamental principles should not be considered as " testable" experimentally,   that they should be considered as disguised definitions.